# Parallelizing with Ray and getting results with a timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, ray

I'm facing an issue with a parallelized document scraper I've made.

I'm using the Ray library and the `@ray.remote` decorator which is working great. The problems occur when fetching the results. This is a snippit of my code:

```
ray.init(num_cpus=n_workers)
futures = [worker.remote(x) for x in path_and_dest]

# get results
for doc in futures:
    try:
        ray.get(doc, timeout = timeout)
        pbar1.update(1) # add 1 to success bar
    except RayTimeoutError:
        pbar2.update(1) # add 1 to failure bar
    except Exception as error:
        print("function raised %s" % error)
        print(error.traceback)
```

The `worker` function scrapes a document given a path and saves the output to a destination (given as arguments in the `path_and_dest` variable). The functionallity I'm trying to implement would kill a process if it takes longer than a set `timeout` (in seconds) to scrape the document.

## Problem:

Currently all processes hang if one is "failing" due to the try-except handling and the way I loop over the `futures`-object. For instance if I use 8 cores and all 8 processes exceeds the `timeout` they should all fail at the same time, right now it takes `8 * timeout` seconds for all of them to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ray.wait()` api with while loop. The details are in the reference here: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package-ref.html#ray.wait

The main idea is to run a while loop for a certain time and raise timeout error for `wait` futures.

Psuedocode

```
curr = 0
timeout_cnt = 10
while curr < timeout_cnt:
    ready, wait = ray.wait(futures)
    # Do some ready ID processing here.

    curr += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if len(wait) == 0:
        break
```